# Pressing back button from custom layout activity closes app instead of returning to previous screen

Tags: android, button, back

Within my app I have an xml layout called activity_menu which is what the app first loads in to. On this I have a button which sets the content view to a GameView class which extends view. From here I would like to be able to press the android back button and be returned to activity_layout however currently the app just closes. How might I go about solving this?

Comment: you must have cleared app activity history or finishes the last activity on start of another activity. Check this first

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. First you listen when user press back button by `onBackPressed`. Then when user press back button, you will check if the gameView is visible or not, if it's visible you should hide it without finish the `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(//gameView is visible){
       // hide gameview without finish Activity
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yeah most of things i've seen seem to be suggesting similar however I don't seem to be able to use onBackPressed() in my gameView class as it is not recognised

Comment: override `onBackPressed()` inside the Activity that contains gameview

Answer (score 0):

With the BackButton you navigate to the previous Activity ... As far is i get your app your gameView is the same Activity so the previous is your home screen:

you can Override the onBackPress() method in your Activity:

```
 @Override
 void onBackPress(){
  if(contentView is gameview){
     -> back to activity layout
  }else{
    super.onBackPress()
  }

 }
```

**Update:**

To check if your gameView is enabled you could use a simple boolean flag, or the gameview's visibilty if you work with hide and unhide

Answer (score 0):

I think you has tow activity: MenuActivity(first activity) and GameActivity(second activity), right?
In this case, you just should finish the MenuActivity when jump to GameActivity.

code sample:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, GameActivity.class));
            MenuActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```